# proper getnext logic in a pass_persist handler

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp

I'm working on a small script that'll act as an snmp pass_persist handler. I want it to read a file in (called 'numbers', for now in the same dir) which just contains some integers and return these as an oid tree.

I've been stuck on this for a few days now, and I realise now it's due to a *fundamental misunderstanding* of how snmpd works. I'm using the snmpd.conf man page which makes no mention of any difference in how 'get' and 'getnext' requests are to be handled, but I assume there is one. I can't for the life of me get snmpwalk to work with this script.

Could someone who knows a little more about snmp look this code over ? I've seen several other versions of pass scripts, including a few in python but I've not been able to see from looking at the code how they handle the protocol differently to my code. I saw one implementation that handled a blank command ( '' ), but others that apparently didn't.

Basically, I'm pretty confused at this point ! - It's also proving pretty hard to debug snmpd as it's the one calling my script, not me. I'm logging what i can, and running snmpd in the foreground, but other than that it's all a bit "black-box".

Can anyone shed some light ?

i.e:
numbers file:

```
101
102
103
I want returned as:
.1.3.6.1.4.1..[snip]..1 = 101
.1.3.6.1.4.1..[snip]..2 = 102
.1.3.6.1.4.1..[snip]..3 = 103
```

My script (I'm not worried about returning anything other than integers, and i know the file close will never be reached, but it makes me feel better):

```
#!/bin/python -u

import os,sys, syslog

def getLine():
    return sys.stdin.readline().strip()

def getFileLine(sub_oid, lines):
    sub_oid = int(sub_oid)
    if sub_oid >= len(lines):
        return 'NONE'
    else:
        return lines[sub_oid]

def printOutput(oid, var_type, varbind_value):
    if varbind_value == 'NONE':
        print 'NONE'
    else:
        print oid
        print var_type
        print varbind_value

######################################################

sub_oid = 0
FH = open('numbers','r')
lines = FH.readlines()

while True:
    command = getLine()
    syslog.syslog("command: %s" % command)

    if command == 'PING':
        syslog.syslog('got a ping')
        print 'PONG'
    elif command == 'get':
        given_oid = getLine()
        sub_oid = int(given_oid.split('.')[-1])
        varbind_value = getFileLine(sub_oid, lines)
        printOutput(given_oid, 'integer', varbind_value.strip())
    elif command == 'getnext':
        given_oid = getLine()
        syslog.syslog("got a requested oid of: %s" % given_oid)
        sub_oid = int(given_oid.split('.')[-1])
        varbind_value = getFileLine(sub_oid, lines)
        printOutput(given_oid, 'integer', varbind_value.strip())
    else:
        syslog.syslog("Unknown command: %s" % command)

FH.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's an already written [snmp-passpersist Python module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/snmp-passpersist) specifically for this task. Its page has a link to a real-world usage example. An example code for your case is below.

Regarding your specific questions:

1. The description of `getnext` is indeed notoriously unclear in both specification and wikipedia. It is explained well in [TUT:snmpgetnext - Net-SNMP Wiki](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT%3asnmpgetnext).
   In brief, it retrieves *the first valid OID* (and its value) *that goes after the specified one in the agent's hierarchy*. The "hierarchy" here can be represented as an ordered list of all OIDs the agent knows of that are valid at the moment.

   - There are two major use cases for this:

     1. The response *contains the OID* of that "next" value as well as the value itself. So you can *walk the hierarchy* at the agent by using returned OIDs in subsequent requests. The agent is supposed to return the "not found" error (and `pass_persist` handler - `"NONE"`) when the hierarchy is exhausted.
     2. You can *specify an incomplete OID* too, and the agent is supposed to return *the first complete one it knows of* that matches the one provided.
   - At packet level, `getnext` is indeed different from `get` too (its request type ID is `1`, `get`'s is `0`).
   - You might want to ignore this "magic" altogether and handle it the same way as `get`: this only means that "walking" and "guessing" will not work (walking might loop indefinitely). This is how a handler I maintained at my last occupation worked **and this is just what is happening in your present code too :^)**.
   - - So, the fix is simple: `getFileLine(int(sub_oid)+1, lines)` - since your code is already smart enough to return `"NONE"` on exhaustion. "Guessing" will still not work, but... do you need it?
2. `net-snmpd` has a plethora of logging options - search "log" on [its manpage](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.html) (and, hell, it's free software! you can always consult or even debug the source when all else fails). But in this particular case, logging stdin and stdout while giving queries with `snmpget`/`snmpgetnext` and/or using sniffer is more than enough.

With the aforementioned `snmp-passpersist`, your code boils down to:

```
base_oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1..[snip]"
data_file="<path>"

import snmp_passpersist as snmp
pp=snmp.PassPersist(base_oid)

for l in (l.rstrip() for l in open(data_file)):
    pp.add_int(l,int(l))

pp.start(user_func=lambda:True,refresh=1800)  # If data updates are needed,
                                              # replace lambda with a real fn
                                              # and adjust refresh (sec)
```

If you need to monitor changes to the file, you can either poll it (like the comment above suggests to) or (in Linux) use something like [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki) - in this case, you'll probably need to replace `pp.main_update()` before calling `pp.start()` or otherwise patch up the module's machinery somehow.

Comment: I know of the pre-exsiting module, but i was hoping to avoid any external dependencies. Thanks for the pointers though, it helps alot. Given the issues with the inotify being needed, I might just have to suck it up though. As you say, it would be better (easier!) to use existing code.

Comment: Well, if you read carefully, I provided a fix for your existing code too.

Comment: The snmp-passpersist code you mention seems to work if I walk the exact oid, but if i walk anything higher i just get No such instance currently exists at this OID. Is that module meant to support getnext / walking, or is that similar to my original code ?

Comment: See `pass_persist.PassPersist.get_next()` code for its `getnext` magic. It pretty much conforms to what I formulated in the answer.